# Importing variable names into class namespace

Tags: python

Is it possible to import global variables into an object's instance namespace?

In a structure like this:

```
./mypackage/module1.py
./config.py
./script1.py
```

If config.py has:

```
#config
MYSETTING=1
```

and script1.py has:

```
#SCRIPT1
from config import *
from mypackage.mymodule import MyClass as MC

obj=MC()
```

module1.py:

```
#Myclass
class MyClass(object):
    def test(self):
        print MYSETTING
```

will give error `NameError: global name "MYSETTING" is not defined`

Is there some way I can import variables from config.py into MyClass namespace as globals without doing enumerated "global x" on each of them?

Comment: You should be importing `config.MYSETTING` in `module1.py`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But is it normal practice to import from parent directory? Can I do in module1.py  `from ..config import *` then?

Comment: sure. I would instead opt for `import config` and then use the `config.MYSETTING` instead of a starred import.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Comment: shouldn't it be `.config`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, the config.py is in parent directory. If I do single point it gives `ImportError: No module named config`

Comment: Basically, what I want is to refer to certain global settings throughout all of my code as globals, no matter whether I refer to them from inside module or from script using that module.

Comment: then add the directory that contains `config.py` to your PATH, or cut the Gordian knot and pass the settings to your class/method.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a little confusing. There are three parts.

`config`: contains variables you want.

`script`: contains your logical code and variables imported from `config`.

`module`: contains functions' definition.

When you call `MC.test`, it will find `MYSETTING` in `module`'s namespace, but what you want is to find in `script`'s namespace. So in `test` function, what you real want is to access parent frame's global namespace.

In this case, you need to use `inspect` built-in module.

```
import inspect

print(inspect.current_frame().f_back.f_globals["MYSETTING"])
```

`inspect.current_frame()` will return current frame, and `f_back` refers to parent frame which is the frame calling this function, then `f_globals` refers to frame's `globals()`